# How to extract documentation from SpringShell @ShellMethod annotations

Tags: java, documentation, introspection, spring-shell

I am developing a shell from SpringShell and use the @ShellMethod to annotate the methods that are invoquable from the Shell. The annotation includes a brief description of the command/method.

```
@ShellMethod("this command does something")
```

Now, I would like to generate a documentation that aggregates in a single output all these descriptions. I am guessing that there exists already a library that allows this.

Am I right?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looking for a recommendation is off topic here should be asked at the sister site Software recommendations

Comment: Off topic should be at software recommendations